# Java JfileChooser dúvida código

Tags: java

Entendi que aqui eu instancio a classe `JFileChooser`:

```
JFileChooser arquivo = new JFileChooser();
```

Pego o objeto do arquivo e chamo o método da classe `JFileChooser`(me corrijam se eu estiver errado):

```
arquivo.setDialogTitle("Selecionar Arquivo");
arquivo.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
int retorno = arquivo.showOpenDialog(this);
```

No trecho seguinte eu não entendi. Eu chamo o método `getSelectedFile();` da classe `JFileChooser` e depois jogo ele dentro de uma classe? Eu nunca vi isso acontecer em php.

O que aconteceu com `arquivo.getSelectedFile();`? Joguei isso dentro de onde? File file é o que?? num é uma classe incompleta? Ou File file é uma variável file do tipo File?

```
if(retorno == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    File file = arquivo.getSelectedFile();

  jTextField5.setText(file.getPath());

}else {


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem java é uma [linguagem fortemente tipada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_tipada), ou seja, toda variável declarada precisa de um tipo explícito especificado.

O que está ocorrendo nesta linha é que o método [`getSelectedFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile--) retorna o objeto selecionado no componente `JFileChooser`, num tipo chamado [**`File`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html), e você está atribuindo este objeto retornado a variável `file` deste mesmo tipo. O fato do nome da variável ser file é apenas opção do autor do código, não tem nada a ver com o tipo dela, você poderia chamar de `arquivo` também, mas a variável continuaria sendo do tipo `File`.

Não tem nada de anormal ai, é uma atribuição de valor do retorno de um método a uma variável, com diferença que o java exige que a variável declarada a esquerda tenha que informar qual seu tipo.

Comment: O  arquivo.getSelectedFile(); retorna algo tipo new NumseiOque(); é isso??

Comment: @EdenilsonConceição não, esse método, conforme eu expliquei, retorna um path do arquivo selecionado no JFileChooser, e esse path é do tipo File, que é o tipo em java para tratar arquivos do sistema operacional em execução.